# How to stop animation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on an application where navigation is generating some animation effect during classes change while we didn't use any css / jQuery animation

[Full code is given in jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SheikhNaveed/R22Hr/)

Consider how big white letter and orange color from orange class fades out in another. Is there some jquery / css method that can be used to handle this situation?

```
<nav id="lastNavigation" class="d row clearfix">
<aside class="col-xs-11">
    <div class="col-xs-12 lessonNavigation lesson">
        <ul class="expandable">
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>L1<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>

            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"> <span>L2<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>

            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"> <span>L3<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>

            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"> <span>L4<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>

            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>L5<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
</nav>
```

jQuery used is here

```
$('.lessonNavigation li').attr('class', 'dn');
$('.lessonNavigation li:eq(0)').attr('class', 'expanded left');
$('.lessonNavigation li:eq(1)').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
$('.lessonNavigation li:eq(2)').attr('class', 'expanded right');

// ========== Right Arrow and Right Tile moves navigation ================== 
function slidingNavRight() {
$('.lessonNavigation .expanded.left').attr('class', 'dn');
$('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson ').attr('class', 'expanded left');
$('.lessonNavigation .expanded.right').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
$('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson + li ').attr('class', 'expanded right');
}

$('.lessonNavigation').on('click', '.icon-arrow-right, .expanded.right', function () {
if ($('li:last-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
    return false;
}
slidingNavRight.apply('.icon-arrow-right, .expanded.right');
});

// ========== Left Arrow and Left Tile moves navigation ==================  
function slidingNavLeft() {
$('.lessonNavigation .expanded.right').attr('class', 'dn');
$('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson ').attr('class', 'expanded right');
$('.lessonNavigation .expanded.left').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
$('.lessonNavigation .activeLesson').prev().attr('class', 'expanded left');
}
$('.lessonNavigation').on('click', '.icon-arrow-left, .expanded.left', function () {
if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
    return false;
}
slidingNavLeft.apply('.icon-arrow-left, .expanded.left');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your tag **a**

In your bootstrap.css line 291...

```
   a {
      color: #428bca;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.5s;
   }
```

You can just override

```
.expandable a {
    transition-property: none;
    -moz-transition-property: none;
    -webkit-transition-property: none;
    -o-transition-property: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I was searching to fix for days.

Comment: Not a problem...just a tip...always see your inspect tools...I just saw in Chrome inspect that you had this class :). Best of lucky